# Ошибка загрузки после установки Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, загрузка

Ошибка загрузки после установки Ubuntu 16.04:

```
 lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
 lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/vg_VolGroup-lv_root: clean, 60044/2023424 files, 424366/8081408 blocks
```

С чем связана такая ошибка и как её фиксить на этапе установки и на этапе загрузки?

Comment: приведённые сообщения не содержат ни слова о каких-либо ошибках. это просто информационные сообщения.

Comment: Это всё, что выдаёт система при загрузке.

Comment: @alexander barakin Да, но на это сообщение пропадает заставка Ubuntu и показывается убогий чёрный экран с этой раздражающей строчкой. Как убрать её отображение так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл такой рецепт для продолжения загрузки:

- Нажимаем правый Shift при загрузке и выходим в текстовое загрузочное меню
- Нажимаем клавишу 'e' на пункте загрузки
- Находим строку, содержащую параметры 'quiet splash' и ставим после них параметр 'nomodeset'
- Нажимаем 'F10' для продолжения загрузки

Comment: Если установить nomodeset, система при загрузке выдаёт вместо заставки тонну букв. Я пробовал делать так, как пишут в такой же теме на английском, In /etc/default/grub, change:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"

Then add this line: GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
Run update-grub and reboot for the changes to take effect. Но это делает ещё хуже. Не делайте так.